# undefined method `bson_type' in mongoid add_to_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

not sure what I'm doing wrong when adding an object to set, I'm getting the error `undefined method 'bson_type' for #<Favorite:0x007ffadd59ba48>` at the following line

```
favorite = Favorite.new(
        item_id: params[:item_id],
        item_type: params[:item_type],
        duid: params[:duid],
        name: params[:name]
)

profile.add_to_set(favorites: favorite)
```

models

```
class Favorite
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :profile
  field :item_id, type: String
  field :item_type, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  field :duid, type: String
end
class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :profile_id, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  field :image, type: String
  embeds_many :favorites
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this issue is to use:

```
favorite = Favorite.new(item_id: params[:item_id], ... yada yada)
favorite.profile = profile
favorite.save!
```

Another way to solve this issue is to use the following code -- which I personally prefer:

```
profile.favorites.create!( item_id: params[:item_id], ...yada yada )
```

---

**Extra Info** can be ignored

```
class Profile
  ...
  embeds_many :favorites, cascade_callbacks: true
  ...
end
```

to allow the running of the callbacks found in the `Favorite` model

Comment: If I want to avoid duplicates like the add to set method, I guess I'll have to iterate through and check the embedded collection manually berfore I do the insert?

Comment: or you can force the uniqueness validation on the favorite model... so `profile.favorites.create!` fails if this validation is not met.. you can refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338757/how-to-enforce-unique-embedded-document-in-mongoid) specially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5155240/1769515) rather than iterating over docs (i think this will have slightly better performance, but i'm not sure cause the embedded docs are already loaded in the profile)